# Azure devops error : This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above

Tags: npm, azure-devops

I am getting the following error in Azure DevOps build the pipeline. This works perfectly fine in the local environment.

The error is thrown in `ng e2e` step. I am on Angular 7.1 version.

```
2018-12-23T11:09:23.7978210Z ##[section]Starting: Run e2e
2018-12-23T11:09:23.7982921Z ==============================================================================
2018-12-23T11:09:23.7983079Z Task         : npm
2018-12-23T11:09:23.7983172Z Description  : Install and publish npm packages, or run an npm command. Supports npmjs.com and authenticated registries like Package Management.
2018-12-23T11:09:23.7983263Z Version      : 1.144.0
2018-12-23T11:09:23.7983316Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-12-23T11:09:23.7983401Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613746)
2018-12-23T11:09:23.7983480Z ==============================================================================
2018-12-23T11:09:24.2946060Z SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
2018-12-23T11:09:24.3883866Z SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
2018-12-23T11:09:24.6106087Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" --version"
2018-12-23T11:09:25.3644361Z 6.4.1
2018-12-23T11:09:27.0143140Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" config list"
2018-12-23T11:09:27.8299297Z ; cli configs
2018-12-23T11:09:27.8299516Z metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
2018-12-23T11:09:27.8299587Z scope = ""
2018-12-23T11:09:27.8299667Z user-agent = "npm/6.4.1 node/v8.12.0 win32 x64"
2018-12-23T11:09:27.8299713Z 
2018-12-23T11:09:27.8299768Z ; environment configs
2018-12-23T11:09:27.8299845Z cache = "C:\\npm\\cache"
2018-12-23T11:09:27.8299903Z prefix = "C:\\npm\\prefix"
2018-12-23T11:09:27.8299985Z userconfig = "D:\\a\\1\\npm\\19427.npmrc"
2018-12-23T11:09:27.8300028Z 
2018-12-23T11:09:27.8300099Z ; builtin config undefined
2018-12-23T11:09:27.8300137Z 
2018-12-23T11:09:27.8300196Z ; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
2018-12-23T11:09:27.8300282Z ; cwd = D:\a\1\s\client
2018-12-23T11:09:27.8300340Z ; HOME = C:\Users\VssAdministrator
2018-12-23T11:09:27.8300451Z ; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
2018-12-23T11:09:27.8300495Z 
2018-12-23T11:09:27.8300930Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" run e2e:ci"
2018-12-23T11:09:30.8886103Z events.js:183
2018-12-23T11:09:30.8886306Z       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2018-12-23T11:09:30.8929743Z       ^
2018-12-23T11:09:30.8929831Z 
2018-12-23T11:09:30.8929890Z Error: read ECONNRESET
2018-12-23T11:09:30.8929964Z     at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:622:25)
2018-12-23T11:09:30.8930031Z npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2018-12-23T11:09:30.8930094Z npm ERR! errno 1
2018-12-23T11:09:30.8930157Z npm ERR! icepp@0.0.1 e2e:ci: `ng e2e --configuration=ci`
2018-12-23T11:09:30.8930238Z npm ERR! Exit status 1
2018-12-23T11:09:30.8930294Z npm ERR! 
2018-12-23T11:09:30.8930362Z npm ERR! Failed at the icepp@0.0.1 e2e:ci script.
2018-12-23T11:09:30.8930448Z npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-12-23T11:09:30.8930548Z 
2018-12-23T11:09:30.8930611Z npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2018-12-23T11:09:30.8930709Z npm ERR!     C:\npm\cache\_logs\2018-12-23T11_09_30_852Z-debug.log
2018-12-23T11:09:30.8930759Z 
2018-12-23T11:09:30.8930816Z > icepp@0.0.1 e2e:ci D:\a\1\s\client
2018-12-23T11:09:30.8930888Z > ng e2e --configuration=ci
2018-12-23T11:09:30.8930927Z 
2018-12-23T11:09:30.8931013Z [11:09:30] I/file_manager - creating folder D:\a\1\s\client\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium
2018-12-23T11:09:30.8931178Z [11:09:30] I/config_source - curl -oD:\a\1\s\client\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chrome-response.xml https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9440180Z Found npm debug log, make sure the path matches with the one in npm's output: C:\npm\cache\_logs\2018-12-23T11_09_30_852Z-debug.log
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9440341Z 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9440416Z 1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9440540Z 1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9442090Z 1 verbose cli   'run',
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9442167Z 1 verbose cli   'e2e:ci' ]
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9442227Z 2 info using npm@6.4.1
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9442298Z 3 info using node@v8.12.0
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9442532Z 4 verbose run-script [ 'pree2e:ci', 'e2e:ci', 'poste2e:ci' ]
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9442602Z 5 info lifecycle icepp@0.0.1~pree2e:ci: icepp@0.0.1
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9442681Z 6 info lifecycle icepp@0.0.1~e2e:ci: icepp@0.0.1
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9442752Z 7 verbose lifecycle icepp@0.0.1~e2e:ci: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9443270Z 8 verbose lifecycle icepp@0.0.1~e2e:ci: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\a\1\s\client\node_modules\.bin;C:\agents\2.144.0\externals\git\cmd;C:\tools\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\mysql-5.7.21-winx64\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_192\bin;C:\npm\prefix;C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Ruby\2.5.0\x64\bin;C:\Go1.11\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\ProgramData\Chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Docker;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\ServiceFabricLocalClusterManager;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files\Mercurial;C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9444142Z 9 verbose lifecycle icepp@0.0.1~e2e:ci: CWD: D:\a\1\s\client
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9444233Z 10 silly lifecycle icepp@0.0.1~e2e:ci: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'ng e2e --configuration=ci' ]
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9444330Z 11 silly lifecycle icepp@0.0.1~e2e:ci: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9444416Z 12 info lifecycle icepp@0.0.1~e2e:ci: Failed to exec e2e:ci script
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9444491Z 13 verbose stack Error: icepp@0.0.1 e2e:ci: `ng e2e --configuration=ci`
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9444567Z 13 verbose stack Exit status 1
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9444648Z 13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9444737Z 13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9444816Z 13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9444920Z 13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9444998Z 13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9445080Z 13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9445153Z 13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9445248Z 13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9445316Z 14 verbose pkgid icepp@0.0.1
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9445388Z 15 verbose cwd D:\a\1\s\client
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9445445Z 16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.14393
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9445539Z 17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "e2e:ci"
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9445621Z 18 verbose node v8.12.0
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9445685Z 19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9446141Z 20 error code ELIFECYCLE
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9446212Z 21 error errno 1
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9446271Z 22 error icepp@0.0.1 e2e:ci: `ng e2e --configuration=ci`
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9446347Z 22 error Exit status 1
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9446404Z 23 error Failed at the icepp@0.0.1 e2e:ci script.
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9446483Z 23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9446568Z 24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9446605Z 
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9511523Z ##[error]Error: Npm failed with return code: 1
2018-12-23T11:09:30.9523513Z ##[section]Finishing: Run e2e
```

I am using `Hosted VS2017` agent. I don't think I am missing any module because it works perfectly fine on local environment.

## Build Pipeline

[image]

Comment: Do you use Hosted agent ot Private agent?

Comment: probably missing some module

Comment: If you scroll up, you will see the actual error: `events.js:183: throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event`

Comment: I see this error but not sure why? I am using `Hosted VS2017` agent. I don't think I am missing any module because it works perfectly fine on the local environment.

Comment: Are you sure with all the steps (from a clean clone)? Maybe, `npm install` or some sorts?

Comment: It is always a fresh install. I have added my build pipeline for reference.

Comment: @Schatak No. We moved to `Private agent`

Comment: @Abhishek with Private Agent it is working?

Comment: @Schatak Private agent is working perfectly fine.

Comment: @Abhishek But my build was working fine with the hosted agent earlier, i deployed many times with it

Comment: @Schatak Microsoft keeps upgrading Azure infrastructure.